# ggplot2: How to add dates for plot how many times occur an event in each months

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, charts

I am very new to R. 
I have a .csv where the people upload photos of tiger mosquitoes in Spain. I want to plot how many times We have records each month (June = 25 mosquitoes, January =0 mosquitoes, ...)

This is the .csv [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wnLMVpL70f_M6Q9y5JEVzkqAXIk3pJSR/view?usp=sharing)

My code is this:

```
    #MOSQUITOS
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)



  dfmosquitoe <- read.csv("C:/Users/.....mos.csv",encoding = "ASCII", header = TRUE, sep 
  = ",")

   dfmosquitoe$Date <- as.Date(dfmosquitoe$Date,
                            "%Y-%m-%d")


  #######MUTATE DESCENDENT####################
  dfmosquitoe %>%
  mutate(Municipality = fct_reorder(Municipality, Date)) %>%


  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Date)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.8)   + coord_flip() +
  geom_text(data=dfmosquitoe,aes(y=Date,label=Date),vjust=0)  +


  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Since links will invariably break over time, can you instead share your dataset via code added directly to your question?  To do this, paste the output of the function `dput(dfmosquitoe)`.  This allows everyone to copy and paste that output to recreate your dataframe.  This will help answer you question immensely.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that `geom_bar(stat = "identity", ...)` is the same but more keystrokes than `geom_col(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look at the `group_by()` and `count()` functions from `dplyr`. Together they allow you to aggregate your data.

For example:

```
dfmosquitoe %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  count() %>% 

  ggplot(aes(Date, n)) +
  geom_col()
```

This groups the data by date.

[image]

I see gather that you would like to do this by month, which you could do like so:

```
month_tbl <- tibble(month_num = 1:12,
                    Month = factor(month.name, levels = month.name))

dfmosquitoe %>% 
  mutate(month_num = format(Date,"%m"),
         month_num = as.integer(month_num)) %>% 
  group_by(month_num) %>% 
  count() %>% 

  full_join(month_tbl) %>% 
  arrange(month_num) %>% 
   replace_na(list(n=0)) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(Month, n)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

This extracts the month as a number in a new column, aggregates the data then adds on some labels so that each month is easy to identify.

---

**Edit:**
Since you are new note that in the second example I encoded `Month` as a `factor` to keep the correct order of the dates and that I used a `full_join()` after aggregating to add all the months. Even those with no observations. Lastly I replaced the NA values for these months with no observations with 0.